# Creating a second index column to get a 2-level MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, regression, multi-index

I am trying to estimate a panel regression (see: https://bashtage.github.io/linearmodels/doc/panel/examples/examples.html)

My data is formatted like that (thats just an example snippet; in the orginal file there are 11 columns plus the timestamp and thousands of rows):

**What I have**

```
    Country Dummy Timestamp     All Countries
1   1             1993-11-01    6.18    
2   1             11993-11-02   6.18    
3   1             1993-11-03    6.17    
4   1             1993-11-04    6.17    
5   1             1993-11-05    6.40    
6   2             1993-11-01    6.18
7   2             1993-11-02    6.18
8   2             1993-11-03    6.18
9   2             1993-11-04    7.50    
10  2             1993-11-01    7.60
11  3             1993-11-01    7.69
12  3             1993-11-02    7.61
13  3             1993-11-03    7.67
14  3             1993-11-04    7.91
15  3             1993-11-01    8.61
```

**How you can re-create it**

```
import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.DataFrame({"Timestamp" : ['1993-11-01' ,'1993-11-02', '1993-11-03', '1993-11-04','1993-11-15'], "Austria" : [6.18 ,6.18, 6.17, 6.17, 6.40],"Belgium" : [7.05, 7.05, 7.2, 7.5, 7.6],"France" : [7.69, 7.61, 7.67, 7.91, 8.61]},index = [1, 2, 3,4,5])

    Timestamp   Austria Belgium France
1   1993-11-01  6.18    7.05    7.69
2   1993-11-02  6.18    7.05    7.61
3   1993-11-03  6.17    7.20    7.67
4   1993-11-04  6.17    7.50    7.91
5   1993-11-15  6.40    7.60    8.61


index_data['Country Dummy'] = index_data['Country Dummy'].factorize()[0] + 1
                     # pd.Categorical(out['Country Dummy']).codes + 1
index_data
```

**What I do 1.**

```
timestamp = pd.Categorical(index_data['Timestamp'])
index_data = index_data.set_index(['Timestamp', 'Country Dummy'])
index_data['Timestamp'] = timestamp
print(index_data.head())
```

**What I get 1.**

```
    Country Dummy Timestamp     All Countries
1   1             1993-11-01    6.18    
2   1             11993-11-02   6.18    
3   1             1993-11-03    6.17    
4   1             1993-11-04    6.17    
5   1             1993-11-05    6.40    
6   2             1993-11-01    6.18
7   2             1993-11-02    6.18
8   2             1993-11-03    6.18
9   2             1993-11-04    7.50    
10  2             1993-11-01    7.60
11  3             1993-11-01    7.69
12  3             1993-11-02    7.61
13  3             1993-11-03    7.67
14  3             1993-11-04    7.91
15  3             1993-11-01    8.61
```

**What I do 2.**

Then I try to do the regression:

```
!pip install linearmodels
import statsmodels.api as sm
from linearmodels import PanelOLS

exog_vars = ['D_pre_emu','D_post_emu']
exog = sm.add_constant(index_data[exog_vars])
mod = PooledOLS(index_data.All_Countries, exog)
pooled_res = mod.fit()
print(pooled_res)
```

**What I get 2.**

But I get the error: "ValueError: exog does not have full column rank."

**Question**

Anyone an idea what could cause that problem?

**Idea**

Is it because my data should be formatted like that (see example in link at the top):
--> and if yes, how could I get that

```
    Country Dummy Timestamp     All Countries
1   1             1993-11-01    6.18    
2                 1993-11-02    6.18    
3                 1993-11-03    6.17    
4                 1993-11-04    6.17    
5                 1993-11-05    6.40    
6   2             1993-11-01    6.18
7                 1993-11-02    6.18
8                 1993-11-03    6.18
9                 1993-11-04    7.50    
10                1993-11-01    7.60
11  3             1993-11-01    7.69
12                1993-11-02    7.61
13                1993-11-03    7.67
14                1993-11-04    7.91
15                1993-11-01    8.61
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `melt` to transform the data and `factorize` to get the dummy:

```
out = df.melt('Timestamp', var_name='Country Dummy', value_name='All Countries')

out['Country Dummy'] = out['Country Dummy'].factorize()[0] + 1
                     # pd.Categorical(out['Country Dummy']).codes + 1
```

Output:

```
     Timestamp  Country Dummy  All Countries
0   1993-11-01              1           6.18
1   1993-11-02              1           6.18
2   1993-11-03              1           6.17
3   1993-11-04              1           6.17
4   1993-11-15              1           6.40
5   1993-11-01              2           7.05
6   1993-11-02              2           7.05
7   1993-11-03              2           7.20
8   1993-11-04              2           7.50
9   1993-11-15              2           7.60
10  1993-11-01              3           7.69
11  1993-11-02              3           7.61
12  1993-11-03              3           7.67
13  1993-11-04              3           7.91
14  1993-11-15              3           8.61
```

Comment: Added one more way to the answer. Feel free to revert if not ok.

Comment: Thank you guys! That works perfectly fine! I forgot to mention that I have two additional columns (see edit at the bottom of the page). How can I make sure that they are also in the 2-index panda?

Comment: `df.melt(['Timestamp','Pre', 'Post'],...)`.